# Twitter-like login system (passing parameters in URL?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, parameters, routes, twitter

How do you pass parameters in a URL? I'm trying to design a login system similar to Twitter's. Notice how you can either login to the main page of www.twitter.com or you can go directly to customised pages such as www.twitter.com/lancearmstrong and www.twitter.com/rails . That's exactly what I need for my project. Thanks.

Comment: I do not get any kind of login form on twitter.com/rails when I'm not logged in.  What exactly are you talking about?

Comment: My apologies. Well imagine you get the username and password fields aswell on any user's twitter page. That's what I am after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in config/routes.rb create a rule like this:

```
  map.connect '/:user_name', :controller => 'login', :action => 'custom'
```

or somethjing similar.

then in your controller pick up the user name with params[:user_name]

This should go at the end of the file near the default rules. The system chooses the first route that matches the incoming URL. so if you have a rule like:

```
  map.connect '/foo', :controller => 'foo', :action => 'bar'
```

it will need to come before the login rule. - bear in mind that if you do this you will have to disallow 'foo' as a username :)

Comment: "then in your controller pick up the user name with params[:user_name]"

Would I do this in the 'custom' action according to your example. 

Say: 

def custom
  # do something with params[:user_name]
end

Comment: Yes, correct. Though obviously it doesn't have to be called 'custom' I just took that name from the word 'customised' in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Apache's mod_rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for information on directing `www.mysite.com/asdf` to a CGI script with the argument "`asdf`".